# SAMBA - how to get client IP

Tags: c, samba

I tried to get the client IP with SAMBA by:

```
char *client_ip = tsocket_address_inet_addr_string(handle->conn->sconn->remote_address, talloc_tos());
```

From looking at their source code, I see that ***sconn*** can be NULL (and I am getting NULL)

```
struct smbd_server_connection *sconn; /* can be NULL */
```

So how can I get the client IP?

More specifically 
It is in one of the vfs files. I am trying to get the client IP for logging.

```
static struct vfs_fn_pointers my_vfs = { 
    .rename_fn = my_rename
}; 

static int my_rename(vfs_handle_struct *handle,
                  const struct smb_filename *smb_fname_src,
                  const struct smb_filename *smb_fname_dst)
{
//HERE. HOW TO GET THE CLIENT IP FROM *handle OR ANY OTHER METHOD)
}
```

Comment: That's not possible to answer without more context. What are you doing  ? Where in the samba code base are you doing it, and does that part of the code deal with "clients" ?

Comment: @nos it is in one of the vfs files I am trying to get the client IP for logging.

static struct vfs_fn_pointers my_vfs{ .rename_fn = my_rename....}; 
static int my_rename(vfs_handle_struct *handle,
         const struct smb_filename *smb_fname_src,
         const struct smb_filename *smb_fname_dst)
{

Comment: Well, without more code that shows what you are doing and whether you are doing it in the proper place , I don't see how anyone can help you with this.

Comment: @nos I added more code to clarify. See the upper part of the original question